# I am trying to depict what this java print statement “ (((0xFF << (i * 8)) & test)))) “ means

Tags: java, function, loops

My assignment is to figure out what this java program written by my teacher is doing, without running it. I have attached the whole (short) program and bolded the expression I do not understand. It is apart of the first for loop, which I am also a little unclear as to what it does.

```
import java.util.*;
int intSize = Integer.SIZE / 8; char storage[] = new char[intSize]; int test = 0xffffffff,
 test2 = 0; 

System.out.println(String.format("0x%08x",0xFF << (3 * 8) & test));
storage[0] = (char) ((0xF << 4));

for (int i = intSize - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--)
// storage[i] = (char) ((0xFF << (i * 8)) & test);
     System.out.println(String.format("0x%08x",**(((0xFF << (i * 8)) & test))));** 
for (int i = 0, j = intSize-1; i < intSize ; i++, j--)
     test2 &= (((int) storage[i]) << (j * 8));
System.out.println(“The Magic Word of the Day is the English word for: ”+test2);
```

Comment: You haven't _bolded_ it you have just put double asterisks around it which are ignored as a bolding mechanism when the whole thing is selected as code. You should remove them to not cause additional misunderstandings and leave a comment at the end of the line if you want to clarify something.

Comment: @Kayaman just out of curiosity, what made you decide that the OP's teacher is horrible? And no, I am **not** the OP's teacher  :-)

Comment: I agree that the teacher is kind of horrible.  If they’re going to tell someone to analyze code, they need to make it an ideal example of readable code.  I could easily spend an hour pointing out what’s wrong with this code, even if it is functionally correct.

Comment: @Abra experience. It would be the same as going to a beginner French class, having the  teacher give you a recording of them reading parts of Gerard Depardieu's private diary, then having a pop quiz about the contents.

Comment: Also the code in question will **never** change the value of `test2`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A useful way to analyze what code is doing, is to break it down into the smallest possible steps.

First, there are extra parentheses which are not needed.  So let’s clean that up, by changing this:

```
(((0xFF << (i * 8)) & test))
```

to this, which is exactly the same thing:

```
(0xFF << (i * 8)) & test
```

Now, imagine it broken down into separate steps:

```
int value = i * 8;
int mask = 0xFF << value;
int result = mask & test;
```

So, you know that:

- `value` is a multiple of 8
- `mask` is eight contiguous `1` bits (because 0xFF is 11111111 in base two), shifted by a count which is a multiple of 8
- `result` is the application of that mask to the 32 bits 11111111111111111111111111111111 (which is the base two form of 0xffffffff, which is the value of `test`)

Hopefully, if you’ve been given this assignment, you already understand the purpose of the bitwise `&` operator:  each 1-bit in one operand preserves the corresponding bit in the other operand, while 0-bits in either operand are always cleared in the result.

There a lot of things in this code which are poor practice.  Not challenging, just bad.  You’ve been given an assignment which is much harder than it should be, in my opinion, for the purpose of demonstrating knowledge of Java’s mathematical and bitwise operators.